# Non Restoring Division in Iverilog

Tags: digital-logic, iverilog

I am trying to implement the non-restoring division algorithm in iVerilog. I am able to get the desired final outputs but the intermediate outputs are wrong. What I mean by intermediate outputs are the values stored in the accumulator (A) and dividend(Q) bits after each clock cycle. This is the [Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PodTb.png)

This is the code for the circuit

```
module left_shift(input wire clk,reset,input wire[16:0]A,input wire[15:0]Q,output wire[16:0]A_ls,output wire[15:0]Q_ls);

dfr dfrA_ls0(clk,reset,A[15],A_ls[16]);
dfr dfrA_ls1(clk,reset,A[14],A_ls[15]);
dfr dfrA_ls2(clk,reset,A[13],A_ls[14]);
dfr dfrA_ls3(clk,reset,A[12],A_ls[13]);
dfr dfrA_ls4(clk,reset,A[11],A_ls[12]);
dfr dfrA_ls5(clk,reset,A[10],A_ls[11]);
dfr dfrA_ls6(clk,reset,A[9],A_ls[10]);
dfr dfrA_ls7(clk,reset,A[8],A_ls[9]);
dfr dfrA_ls8(clk,reset,A[7],A_ls[8]);
dfr dfrA_ls9(clk,reset,A[6],A_ls[7]);
dfr dfrA_ls10(clk,reset,A[5],A_ls[6]);
dfr dfrA_ls11(clk,reset,A[4],A_ls[5]);
dfr dfrA_ls12(clk,reset,A[3],A_ls[4]);
dfr dfrA_ls13(clk,reset,A[2],A_ls[3]);
dfr dfrA_ls14(clk,reset,A[1],A_ls[2]);
dfr dfrA_ls15(clk,reset,A[0],A_ls[1]);
dfr dfrA_ls16(clk,reset,Q[15],A_ls[0]);

dfr dfrQ_ls0(clk,reset,Q[14],Q_ls[15]);
dfr dfrQ_ls1(clk,reset,Q[13],Q_ls[14]);
dfr dfrQ_ls2(clk,reset,Q[12],Q_ls[13]);
dfr dfrQ_ls3(clk,reset,Q[11],Q_ls[12]);
dfr dfrQ_ls4(clk,reset,Q[10],Q_ls[11]);
dfr dfrQ_ls5(clk,reset,Q[9],Q_ls[10]);
dfr dfrQ_ls6(clk,reset,Q[8],Q_ls[9]);
dfr dfrQ_ls7(clk,reset,Q[7],Q_ls[8]);
dfr dfrQ_ls8(clk,reset,Q[6],Q_ls[7]);
dfr dfrQ_ls9(clk,reset,Q[5],Q_ls[6]);
dfr dfrQ_ls10(clk,reset,Q[4],Q_ls[5]);
dfr dfrQ_ls11(clk,reset,Q[3],Q_ls[4]);
dfr dfrQ_ls12(clk,reset,Q[2],Q_ls[3]);
dfr dfrQ_ls13(clk,reset,Q[1],Q_ls[2]);
dfr dfrQ_ls14(clk,reset,Q[0],Q_ls[1]);

endmodule

module cycle_div(input wire clk,reset,input wire[16:0]A,M,input wire[15:0]Q,output wire[15:0]quo,output wire[16:0]rem);

    wire A_MSB;
    assign A_MSB=A[16];
    wire A_Msb_Op;
    invert inv_MSB(A_MSB,A_Msb_Op);

    wire [16:0]B;

    xor2 xor_0(M[0],A_Msb_Op,B[0]);
    xor2 xor_1(M[1],A_Msb_Op,B[1]);
    xor2 xor_2(M[2],A_Msb_Op,B[2]);
    xor2 xor_3(M[3],A_Msb_Op,B[3]);
    xor2 xor_4(M[4],A_Msb_Op,B[4]);
    xor2 xor_5(M[5],A_Msb_Op,B[5]);
    xor2 xor_6(M[6],A_Msb_Op,B[6]);
    xor2 xor_7(M[7],A_Msb_Op,B[7]);
    xor2 xor_8(M[8],A_Msb_Op,B[8]);
    xor2 xor_9(M[9],A_Msb_Op,B[9]);
    xor2 xor_10(M[10],A_Msb_Op,B[10]);
    xor2 xor_11(M[11],A_Msb_Op,B[11]);
    xor2 xor_12(M[12],A_Msb_Op,B[12]);
    xor2 xor_13(M[13],A_Msb_Op,B[13]);
    xor2 xor_14(M[14],A_Msb_Op,B[14]);
    xor2 xor_15(M[15],A_Msb_Op,B[15]);
    xor2 xor_16(M[16],A_Msb_Op,B[16]);

    wire[16:0]A_ls;

    left_shift ls(clk,reset,A,Q,A_ls,quo);

    wire[16:0]carry;

    fa fa_0(A_ls[0],B[0],A_Msb_Op,rem[0],carry[0]);
    fa fa_1(A_ls[1],B[1],carry[0],rem[1],carry[1]);
    fa fa_2(A_ls[2],B[2],carry[1],rem[2],carry[2]);
    fa fa_3(A_ls[3],B[3],carry[2],rem[3],carry[3]);
    fa fa_4(A_ls[4],B[4],carry[3],rem[4],carry[4]);
    fa fa_5(A_ls[5],B[5],carry[4],rem[5],carry[5]);
    fa fa_6(A_ls[6],B[6],carry[5],rem[6],carry[6]);
    fa fa_7(A_ls[7],B[7],carry[6],rem[7],carry[7]);
    fa fa_8(A_ls[8],B[8],carry[7],rem[8],carry[8]);
    fa fa_9(A_ls[9],B[9],carry[8],rem[9],carry[9]);
    fa fa_10(A_ls[10],B[10],carry[9],rem[10],carry[10]);
    fa fa_11(A_ls[11],B[11],carry[10],rem[11],carry[11]);
    fa fa_12(A_ls[12],B[12],carry[11],rem[12],carry[12]);
    fa fa_13(A_ls[13],B[13],carry[12],rem[13],carry[13]);
    fa fa_14(A_ls[14],B[14],carry[13],rem[14],carry[14]);
    fa fa_15(A_ls[15],B[15],carry[14],rem[15],carry[15]);
    fa fa_16(A_ls[16],B[16],carry[15],rem[16],carry[16]);


    wire x=1'b1;
    xor2 xor_LSB(x,rem[16],quo[0]);

endmodule

module division(input wire clk,reset,input wire[15:0]dividend,divisor,output wire[15:0]quotient,output wire[16:0]remainder);


wire [16:0]A;
wire x=1'b1;
wire y=1'b0;

dfr dfrA_0(clk,reset,y,A[0]);
dfr dfrA_1(clk,reset,y,A[1]);
dfr dfrA_2(clk,reset,y,A[2]);
dfr dfrA_3(clk,reset,y,A[3]);
dfr dfrA_4(clk,reset,y,A[4]);
dfr dfrA_5(clk,reset,y,A[5]);
dfr dfrA_6(clk,reset,y,A[6]);
dfr dfrA_7(clk,reset,y,A[7]);
dfr dfrA_8(clk,reset,y,A[8]);
dfr dfrA_9(clk,reset,y,A[9]);
dfr dfrA_10(clk,reset,y,A[10]);
dfr dfrA_11(clk,reset,y,A[11]);
dfr dfrA_12(clk,reset,y,A[12]);
dfr dfrA_13(clk,reset,y,A[13]);
dfr dfrA_14(clk,reset,y,A[14]);
dfr dfrA_15(clk,reset,y,A[15]);
dfr dfrA_16(clk,reset,y,A[16]);


wire [16:0]A_temp1;
wire [16:0]A_temp2;
wire [16:0]A_temp3;
wire [16:0]A_temp4;
wire [16:0]A_temp5;
wire [16:0]A_temp6;
wire [16:0]A_temp7;
wire [16:0]A_temp8;
wire [16:0]A_temp9;
wire [16:0]A_temp10;
wire [16:0]A_temp11;
wire [16:0]A_temp12;
wire [16:0]A_temp13;
wire [16:0]A_temp14;
wire [16:0]A_temp15;
wire [16:0]A_temp16;


wire [16:0]M;

assign M=divisor;

wire [15:0]Q;
wire [15:0]Q_temp[0:15];
assign Q=dividend;

cycle_div div_0(clk,reset,A,M,Q,Q_temp[0],A_temp1);
cycle_div div_1(clk,reset,A_temp1,M,Q_temp[0],Q_temp[1],A_temp2);
cycle_div div_2(clk,reset,A_temp2,M,Q_temp[1],Q_temp[2],A_temp3);
cycle_div div_3(clk,reset,A_temp3,M,Q_temp[2],Q_temp[3],A_temp4);
cycle_div div_4(clk,reset,A_temp4,M,Q_temp[3],Q_temp[4],A_temp5);
cycle_div div_5(clk,reset,A_temp5,M,Q_temp[4],Q_temp[5],A_temp6);
cycle_div div_6(clk,reset,A_temp6,M,Q_temp[5],Q_temp[6],A_temp7);
cycle_div div_7(clk,reset,A_temp7,M,Q_temp[6],Q_temp[7],A_temp8);
cycle_div div_8(clk,reset,A_temp8,M,Q_temp[7],Q_temp[8],A_temp9);
cycle_div div_9(clk,reset,A_temp9,M,Q_temp[8],Q_temp[9],A_temp10);
cycle_div div_10(clk,reset,A_temp10,M,Q_temp[9],Q_temp[10],A_temp11);
cycle_div div_11(clk,reset,A_temp11,M,Q_temp[10],Q_temp[11],A_temp12);
cycle_div div_12(clk,reset,A_temp12,M,Q_temp[11],Q_temp[12],A_temp13);
cycle_div div_13(clk,reset,A_temp13,M,Q_temp[12],Q_temp[13],A_temp14);
cycle_div div_14(clk,reset,A_temp14,M,Q_temp[13],Q_temp[14],A_temp15);
cycle_div div_15(clk,reset,A_temp15,M,Q_temp[14],quotient,A_temp16);

wire [16:0]B;

mux2 mux_0(y,M[0],A_temp16[16],B[0]);
mux2 mux_1(y,M[1],A_temp16[16],B[1]);
mux2 mux_2(y,M[2],A_temp16[16],B[2]);
mux2 mux_3(y,M[3],A_temp16[16],B[3]);
mux2 mux_4(y,M[4],A_temp16[16],B[4]);
mux2 mux_5(y,M[5],A_temp16[16],B[5]);
mux2 mux_6(y,M[6],A_temp16[16],B[6]);
mux2 mux_7(y,M[7],A_temp16[16],B[7]);
mux2 mux_8(y,M[8],A_temp16[16],B[8]);
mux2 mux_9(y,M[9],A_temp16[16],B[9]);
mux2 mux_10(y,M[10],A_temp16[16],B[10]);
mux2 mux_11(y,M[11],A_temp16[16],B[11]);
mux2 mux_12(y,M[12],A_temp16[16],B[12]);
mux2 mux_13(y,M[13],A_temp16[16],B[13]);
mux2 mux_14(y,M[14],A_temp16[16],B[14]);
mux2 mux_15(y,M[15],A_temp16[16],B[15]);
mux2 mux_16(y,M[16],A_temp16[16],B[16]);

wire[16:0]carry;

fa fa_f0(A_temp16[0],B[0],y,remainder[0],carry[0]);
fa fa_f1(A_temp16[1],B[1],carry[0],remainder[1],carry[1]);
fa fa_f2(A_temp16[2],B[2],carry[1],remainder[2],carry[2]);
fa fa_f3(A_temp16[3],B[3],carry[2],remainder[3],carry[3]);
fa fa_f4(A_temp16[4],B[4],carry[3],remainder[4],carry[4]);
fa fa_f5(A_temp16[5],B[5],carry[4],remainder[5],carry[5]);
fa fa_f6(A_temp16[6],B[6],carry[5],remainder[6],carry[6]);
fa fa_f7(A_temp16[7],B[7],carry[6],remainder[7],carry[7]);
fa fa_f8(A_temp16[8],B[8],carry[7],remainder[8],carry[8]);
fa fa_f9(A_temp16[9],B[9],carry[8],remainder[9],carry[9]);
fa fa_f10(A_temp16[10],B[10],carry[9],remainder[10],carry[10]);
fa fa_f11(A_temp16[11],B[11],carry[10],remainder[11],carry[11]);
fa fa_f12(A_temp16[12],B[12],carry[11],remainder[12],carry[12]);
fa fa_f13(A_temp16[13],B[13],carry[12],remainder[13],carry[13]);
fa fa_f14(A_temp16[14],B[14],carry[13],remainder[14],carry[14]);
fa fa_f15(A_temp16[15],B[15],carry[14],remainder[15],carry[15]);
fa fa_f16(A_temp16[16],B[16],carry[15],remainder[16],carry[16]);
endmodule
```

Test-bench :

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps
`define TESTVECS 8

module tb;
    reg clk,reset;
    initial begin
        $dumpfile("tb_nr_div.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0,tb);
    end
    initial begin #5 reset = 1'b1; #10 reset = 1'b0;end
    initial clk = 1'b0; always #5 clk =~ clk;
    integer i;
    reg[15:0]dividend;
    reg[15:0]divisor;
    wire[15:0]quotient;
    wire[16:0]remainder;
    reg[31:0]test_vecs[0:(`TESTVECS-1)];
    initial begin
        test_vecs[0][31:16]=16'h15;test_vecs[0][15:0]=16'h4; 
        test_vecs[1][31:16]=16'h7;test_vecs[1][15:0]=16'h3;
        test_vecs[2][31:16]=16'hFFFF;test_vecs[2][15:0]=16'h9A9A;
        test_vecs[3][31:16]=16'hABCD;test_vecs[3][15:0]=16'h1111;
        test_vecs[4][31:16]=16'h1234;test_vecs[4][15:0]=16'h4321; //Divisor > Dividend
        test_vecs[5][31:16]=16'hFFF1;test_vecs[5][15:0]=16'h2755; //Prime divided by prime
        test_vecs[6][31:16]=16'hFFFF;test_vecs[6][15:0]=16'hFFFF; //2^16-1 divided by 2^16-1
        test_vecs[7][31:16]=16'hFFFF;test_vecs[7][15:0]=16'h0001; //2^16-1 divided by 1
    end
    division division_0(clk,reset,dividend,divisor,quotient,remainder);
    initial begin
        #5 for(i=0;i<`TESTVECS;i=i+1)begin
            reset=1'b1;
            #10 reset=1'b0;
            #170 {dividend,divisor}=test_vecs[i];
        end
    #200 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

Library file :

```
module xor2(input wire i0,i1,output wire o);
assign o = i0^i1;
endmodule

module and2(input wire i0,i1, output wire o);
assign o = i0&i1;
endmodule

module or2(input wire i0,i1,output wire o);
assign o=i0|i1;
endmodule

module invert(input wire a,output wire b);
assign b=!a;
endmodule

module df (input wire clk, in, output wire out);
  reg df_out;
  always@(posedge clk) df_out <= in;
  assign out = df_out;
endmodule

module dfr (input wire clk, reset, in, output wire out);
  wire reset_, df_in;
  invert invert_0 (reset, reset_);
  and2 and2_0 (in, reset_, df_in);
  df df_0 (clk, df_in, out);
endmodule

module fa(input wire a,b,cin,output wire sum,cout);
assign sum=a^b^cin;
assign cout= a&b | a&cin | b&cin;
endmodule

module mux2(input wire i0,i1,sel, output wire o);
assign o= (sel==0)?i0:i1;
endmodule
```

This is the GtkWave [image: GtkWave] for the first test-vector. This is [image: GtkWave] for the second test-vector The first 7 rows are the outputs and inputs required.

The next few rows show the intermediate values that need to be stored in the accumulator. However as you can see , the accumulator A_tempX is storing some values before Clock Cycle X is executed. Please help me figure out where I am going wrong.